# magento - get list of products which are in comparison list

Tags: list, magento, comparison, product

i need to get list of products which are in comparison list

i have this code in phtml and it does nothing>

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_compare_list')->getCollection()->load();
                foreach($collection as $product) {
                   echo $product->getId().'<Br />';
                }
```

any suggestions where is problem ? thanks

Comment: without `load` collection is still loading in the next line (`foreach` construction), so although `load` is an excess here, removing it won't change the program logic at all

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `getItems()` method of Compare list block (Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List):

```
$collection = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_compare_list')->getItems();
foreach($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getId().'<Br />';
}
```

Comment: Both yours and Guerra's answer towards `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')`. It's interesting to see the result which one is better :)

Comment: @ivantedja your're right :) but the block method is already prepared for the output - all filters are applied. While the raw collection from the resource model will return the whole collection of compared items, not exactly what you need. Although it's still unclear why it doesn't return anything to the author.

Comment: I don't get it either because I never use compare list, maybe it has a huge amount of data and trigger memory exhausted for unfiltered collection?

Comment: ok it is working with this:    
`$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare');
$_items = $_helper->getItemCount() > 0 ? $_helper->getItemCollection() : null;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_compare_list')->getCollection();
            foreach($collection as $product) {
               echo $product->getId().'<Br />';
            }
```

Comment: hm it prints nothing, i have this code catalog/template/product/list.phtml

Comment: @hazard have you checked `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Compare_List` ? I don't see any `function getCollection()`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_compare_list')->getItemCollection();
        foreach($collection as $product) {
           echo $product->getId().'<Br />';
        }
```

This should work.

Comment: not working, if i use getItemCollection , whole list.phtml dissapear

Comment: this is working, maybe you doint something else wrong. I testing here and this method return all the Item collection, comment foreach statment and print echo count($collection); and see how mutch register this bring